# Not able to add custom rules in checkstyle.xml for Codacy in android studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio-3.0, checkstyle, codacy

I want to add custom rules in checkstyle.xml so that I can view them in codacy Dashboard. I am facing following issues while doing that.

1. I have written a custom class to check unused private methods in a
   classes. It is showing instantiation error in android studio and
   checkstyle documentation does not provide any clues regarding how to
   instantiate custom rule class and add it as module.
2. Checklist.xml is getting configured with Codacy dashboard but not showing 
   details on dashboard itself.
3. Even codacy documentation says that we can add custom XML rules but I am 
   not able to add custom rules for XML in it and project cloned from Github gets 
   recognized as only java project.
   I am sharing below code snippets.

Here is a error from android studio
https://ibb.co/613PL9t

Here is Checkstyle.xml

```
<module name="Checker">
<module name="NewlineAtEndOfFile" />
<module name="FileLength" />
<module name="FileTabCharacter" />
<module name="TreeWalker">
    <module name="packageName.MethodCallWithoutObjectCreation" />
    <module name="ArrayTypeStyle" />
    <module name="UpperEll" />
    <module name="Indentation">
        <property name="caseIndent" value="4" />
    </module>
</module>
```

Here is UnusedPrivateMethodCheck.Java class

```
public class UnusedPrivateMethodCheck
extends AbstractCheck {
/**
 * Controls if checks skips serialization methods.
 */
private boolean mAllowSerializationMethods;


public int[] getDefaultTokens() {
    return new int[]{
        TokenTypes.METHOD_DEF,
    };
}

@Override
public int[] getAcceptableTokens() {
    return new int[0];
}

@Override
public int[] getRequiredTokens() {
    return new int[0];
}

public String getErrorKey() {
    return "unused.method";
}

public void setAllowSerializationMethods(boolean aFlag) {
    mAllowSerializationMethods = aFlag;
}

public boolean mustCheckReferenceCount(DetailAST aAST) {
    final DetailAST mods = aAST.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.MODIFIERS);
    if ((mods == null)
        || (ScopeUtils.getScopeFromMods(mods) != Scope.PRIVATE)) {
        return false;
    }

    return !mAllowSerializationMethods
        || !(isWriteObject(aAST) || isReadObject(aAST)
        || isWriteReplaceOrReadResolve(aAST));
}


/**
 * Checks if a given method is writeObject().
 *
 * @param aAST method def to check
 * @return true if this is a writeObject() definition
 */
private boolean isWriteObject(DetailAST aAST) {
    // name is writeObject...
    final DetailAST ident = aAST.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.IDENT);
    if (!"writeObject".equals(ident.getText())) {
        return false;
    }

    // returns void...
    final DetailAST typeAST =
        (DetailAST) aAST.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.TYPE).getFirstChild();
    if (typeAST.getType() != TokenTypes.LITERAL_VOID) {
        return false;
    }

    // should have one parameter...
    final DetailAST params = aAST.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.PARAMETERS);
    if (params == null || params.getChildCount() != 1) {
        return false;
    }
    // and paramter's type should be java.io.ObjectOutputStream
    final DetailAST type =
        (DetailAST) ((DetailAST) params.getFirstChild())
            .findFirstToken(TokenTypes.TYPE).getFirstChild();
    final String typeName = FullIdent.createFullIdent(type).getText();
    if (!"java.io.ObjectOutputStream".equals(typeName)
        && !"ObjectOutputStream".equals(typeName)) {
        return false;
    }

    // and, finally, it should throws java.io.IOException
    final DetailAST throwsAST =
        aAST.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.LITERAL_THROWS);
    if (throwsAST == null || throwsAST.getChildCount() != 1) {
        return false;
    }
    final DetailAST expt = (DetailAST) throwsAST.getFirstChild();
    final String exceptionName = FullIdent.createFullIdent(expt).getText();
    if (!"java.io.IOException".equals(exceptionName)
        && !"IOException".equals(exceptionName)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Checks if a given method is readObject().
 *
 * @param aAST method def to check
 * @return true if this is a readObject() definition
 */
private boolean isReadObject(DetailAST aAST) {
    // name is readObject...
    final DetailAST ident = aAST.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.IDENT);
    if (!"readObject".equals(ident.getText())) {
        return false;
    }

    // returns void...
    final DetailAST typeAST =
        (DetailAST) aAST.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.TYPE).getFirstChild();
    if (typeAST.getType() != TokenTypes.LITERAL_VOID) {
        return false;
    }

    // should have one parameter...
    final DetailAST params = aAST.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.PARAMETERS);
    if (params == null || params.getChildCount() != 1) {
        return false;
    }
    // and paramter's type should be java.io.ObjectInputStream
    final DetailAST type =
        (DetailAST) ((DetailAST) params.getFirstChild())
            .findFirstToken(TokenTypes.TYPE).getFirstChild();
    final String typeName = FullIdent.createFullIdent(type).getText();
    if (!"java.io.ObjectInputStream".equals(typeName)
        && !"ObjectInputStream".equals(typeName)) {
        return false;
    }

    // and, finally, it should throws java.io.IOException
    // and java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
    final DetailAST throwsAST =
        aAST.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.LITERAL_THROWS);
    if (throwsAST == null || throwsAST.getChildCount() != 3) {
        return false;
    }
    final DetailAST excpt1 = (DetailAST) throwsAST.getFirstChild();
    final String exception1 = FullIdent.createFullIdent(excpt1).getText();
    final String exception2 =
        FullIdent.createFullIdent(throwsAST.getLastChild()).getText();
    if (!"java.io.IOException".equals(exception1)
        && !"IOException".equals(exception1)
        && !"java.io.IOException".equals(exception2)
        && !"IOException".equals(exception2)
        || !"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException".equals(exception1)
        && !"ClassNotFoundException".equals(exception1)
        && !"java.lang.ClassNotFoundException".equals(exception2)
        && !"ClassNotFoundException".equals(exception2)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Checks if a given method is writeReplace() or readResolve().
 *
 * @param aAST method def to check
 * @return true if this is a writeReplace() definition
 */
private boolean isWriteReplaceOrReadResolve(DetailAST aAST) {
    // name is writeReplace or readResolve...
    final DetailAST ident = aAST.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.IDENT);
    if (!"writeReplace".equals(ident.getText())
        && !"readResolve".equals(ident.getText())) {
        return false;
    }

    // returns Object...
    final DetailAST typeAST =
        (DetailAST) aAST.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.TYPE).getFirstChild();
    if (typeAST.getType() != TokenTypes.DOT
        && typeAST.getType() != TokenTypes.IDENT) {
        return false;
    }

    // should have no parameters...
    final DetailAST params = aAST.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.PARAMETERS);
    if (params != null && params.getChildCount() != 0) {
        return false;
    }

    // and, finally, it should throws java.io.ObjectStreamException
    final DetailAST throwsAST =
        aAST.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.LITERAL_THROWS);
    if (throwsAST == null || throwsAST.getChildCount() != 1) {
        return false;
    }
    final DetailAST excpt = (DetailAST) throwsAST.getFirstChild();
    final String exception = FullIdent.createFullIdent(excpt).getText();
    if (!"java.io.ObjectStreamException".equals(exception)
        && !"ObjectStreamException".equals(exception)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

}

For this I am getting error like `Unable to instantiate UnusedPrivateMethodCheckCheck`

Comment: Your screenshot shows different code then what was pasted. `Check` and `AbstractUsageCheck` are not classes of the latest checkstyle. I recommend using the latest version of checkstyle. If you need support with an older version of checkstyle, please specify the version you are using. Also please copy/paste the full text of `unable to instantiate` error message.

Comment: codacy doesn't support custom rules if I recall correctly

Comment: @rveach Thanks for your comment as it really helped me to dig into Checkstyle structure and as per your suggestions I have replaced deprecated classes from checkstyle latest version that is version 8.1 and replaced screenshot also in which it clearly shows **unable to instantiate** error message

Comment: @pedrorijo91 I am concerned about codacy docs in which it is mentioned that you can customize code patterns using different plugins like Checkstyle. I am not able to customize rules it for layout xml file. I am seeking help on the same